# ipad simulator is showing iphone version app on cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have used cocos2d template to create the application. I have created the code to handle iphone and ipad code using if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad condition but whatever option I am selection in simulator iphone or ipad above condition is always failing and always iphone version of code is getting executed. please let me know what setting I am missing. I am using xcode 4.2

Answer (score 1):

check if you app is set as universal. Goto MYGAME at the top of the xcode left colum list, then goto your target, and under IOS Application Target you should find Devices next to it select universal

Comment: unable to see any target section there..is it not available if starting template is cocos2d?

Comment: you're looking at the wrong place. Select the Topmost entry in the Project Navigator (Command+1). It has the name of your project, a blue icon to its left side, and it is two lines high with the second line reading "# targets, .. platforms". When you select that you see the Project & Targets list to the right. Select the target, then the Summary tab, under "iOS Application Target" locate the Devices dropdown and make sure it is set to "Universal". You can also find this setting under Build Settings as "Targeted Device Family".